# Steps to be taken to implement JQgrid in MVC4 Razor,using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-4, jqgrid-asp.net

I am new to this MVC and JQuery, i started building small application using these, i am using MVC4 Razor ,with Entity Framework. i fallowed few online tutorials for the. but nothin is working out properly. i am able to get my Json data from my controller but the data is printing on my view as a java script array, jqgrid is not displaying, i guess my jqgrid itself is not called, or its not being referenced properly. please tel me what are all the things  need to do, and directory structures to be fallowed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get **jqGrid** and other Grids like **Telerik** from **Nuget Package Manager**. Each of them must using their own inbuilt functions to handle the events. You will have to learn them to implement it. You can check demos from below link:

**jqGid:**

[link] http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

**Telerik:**

[link] http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/?mvc

[link]http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/